# How to change IPB static pages? (like contact form)

Tags: html, ipb, invision-power-board

I want to edit contact us page but I cannot find the HTML code anywhere.

I tried:

- Searching all files for text match of contact us page code
- Editing theme code and searching for contact template

Without luck.
If anyone has idea how to change index.php?/contact please tell me.

Also not only contact other pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way I found is to either make a theme hook in on of your applications or a code hook to display your own form and template. Be sure to call the parent function though and return the correct values, if any.

Comment: You mean when I want to edit contact I just add template to the theme called contact and edit it?

Comment: @RADEK a bit late of a reply, but if you make a code hook, you would need to use PHP to change the display and HTML in the template. Theme hooks can be used in plugins and are mostly HTML.